# Java Regex to reduce line feeds

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, newline

I am looking for a more elegant way of reducing the number of line feeds in a string. When a string has instance of ***exactly*** 2 or 9 line feeds, I want to reduce the count by 1. For example:

- 1234\n\n4321foo1234\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n4321 => 1234\n4321foo1234\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n4321

I have a roundabout solution working with multiple *if* statements and *string.replaces*, but I figured this could be done in 1-2 lines. I've played around with lookaheads and lookbehinds, but I have not had any luck there. Also I am stuck with Java 8 for this work.

How can I do it?

Comment: User asks for a regex, all 3 answers use regexes, the regex tag should never have been removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture the first 1 or 8 line breaks and discard the trailing one:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<!\n)(\n{8}|\n)\n(?!\n)", "$1");
```

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I ended up using shmosel's solution.

Answer (score 1):

I used a look-behind and look-ahead here.

```java
String string = "1234\n\n4321foo1234\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n4321";
string = string.replaceAll("(?<!\\n)\\n{9}(?!\\n)", "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
string = string.replaceAll("(?<!\\n)\\n{2}(?!\\n)", "\n");
```

Output

```
1234
4321foo1234







4321
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match 2 newlines, followed by capturing 7 optional newlines.

In the replacement use a single newline and capture group 1.

```
(?<!\n)\n{2}(\n{7})?(?!\n)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q5rEFA/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/UWa8dj)

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?<!\n)\n{2}(\n{7})?(?!\n)", "\n$1");
```